# Download directory from Artifact inside repository JFROG

Tags: api, curl, artifactory

I need to download directory from JFROG specific repository and save it on my local machine with the same name of the directory, I tried this command however it didn't work
`>curl -u username:password -L -XGET "**DIRECTORY_URL**?archiveType=zip" --output C:\copying-artifacts\New`

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

We need to enable the "Enable Folder Download" option in the UI and here is the [link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Artifactory#:%7E:text=Folder%20Download%20Settings-,Enable%20Folder%20Download) for JFrog Documentation.

Also, I recommend referring to the knowledge base article on [how-can-i-download-folders-with-their-content-from-a-repository](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-can-i-download-folders-with-their-content-from-a-repository/) for syntax and usage.